# How to find network interface name from IP Address

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, command-line-interface

What is the terminal command or how can  find network interface name (eg. en0, en1, en3 en8 etc) from an IP address. 
I have a IP address and need to find that IP is assigned to which network interface in macOS.

Comment: in macOS, but you tagged Ubuntu and Linux. Which is it? I'm guessing that `ifconfig` may give you some results?

Comment: Yes.. ifconfig will show that, but also show other stuff.  But I just want interface name en1,en2  eg. Xxxxx 10.20.30.40 results should be en1 or en2

Answer (score 2):

Correct way to do this is :

```
route -n get "yourIPhere" | awk '/interface: / {print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not in front of a computer right now, but something like

```
ifconfig | grep -b1 "youriphere" | awk 'NR==1{print $1}'
```

Should get you in the ballpark.

Comment: Nope its not.. iost showing result - **inet6** and if i remove awk its will show - 
**inet6 xxx::xx:xxxxx:xxxxxxx prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xe 
 inet 20.30.40.540 netmask 0xfffffe00 broadcast 100.100.100.100**
Its not giving en whole line

Answer (score 0):

The other answers mostly ignore one question.Similar IP may be matched,for example,if the network interface is **172.16.1.100**,an IP of **72.16.1.10** will also be matched.
Here is my solution：

```
ifconfig | grep -PB1 "[: ]72.16.1.10[^\d]" | grep -o "^\w*"
or
ifconfig | grep -PB1 "[: ]72.16.1.10[^\d]" | awk -F'[: ]' 'NR==1{print $1}'
```